# Solr 4 - Delete fields from FieldsInfo file

Tags: solr, field, solr4

I am running solr 4 version. I have created million fields in solr using a script . I saw GC has gone very high after adding these fields as every time searcher is open, these fields were loaded.

Now, I want to go back to the stage where my solr cluster was before adding those fields. Even though, I delete documents which has those fields, the cluster is not coming back to what it was as the fields are not getting deleted from fieldsInfo file.

Is there a way we can explicitly tell solr to delete the fields from the fieldsInfo file???

Answer (score 0):

There is a [schema API documented that can delete a field](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/7_4/schema-api.html#delete-a-field). However I don't know if this is already available for Solr 4. You should try if it works.

Comment: Thanks Simulant..Seems like Solr 4 doesnt have this option. I see this Solr 6 and above...Only way might be to create index from scratch again